# Is this a suitable diet for weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss

I am 23 old male and in weigh 62 kg at a height of 5.1. I want to lose weight; how can I alter my diet to better accomplish this?

My food intake and exercise:

- Breakfast: a few grams of chickpeas with 2 chapati
- At 11:30am: Lemon tea
- Lunch: 2 egg whites, 5 chapati, vegetable salads (carrot,radish)
- 4pm: Lemon tea
- 6pm: workout - aerobics, crunches, skipping
- After workout: 1 apple
- Dinner: 5 chapati with dal

Comment: I'm sorry I believe chapati is a bread like thing right?  I only eat Indian occasionally here.  My impression is that your diet sounds like it's heavy in complex carbs with all that chapati. I guess it depends on how much chaptai you're consuming and I have no idea.  You might want to clarify chapati for the people here that don't know exactly how many carbs are in it...

Comment: I would add a banana after workout.

Comment: Voted to close as off topic. The only vague reference to fitness is "At 6pm doing aerobics/crunches".

Comment: The question is how to alter his diet for weight-loss. Seems on-topic to me; body composition is already in-scope.

Comment: @JohnP My trainer only said to follow that type of exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Proper diet is hard to define as such for each and every individual. If you are too lazy, you can use this link: http://www.nhlbi.nih.gov/guidelines/obesity/BMI/bmicalc.htm. It will just tell you if you are overweight or not. 
I believe its best to have a trainer/instructor to guide you properly if you are loosing your form while doing any exercise or use a mirror. And, have a dietician suggest you what to eat as per your work life balance and the amount of workout you do. 
When I had begun gym training, I used Kris Gethin's book as my guide [The Bodybuilding.com: Guide to Your Best Body] and here n there took help from the trainers, which is quite good since it also suggests variations of diet plans.

Comment: I consider BMI one of the worst metrics ever foisted upon an innocent public. I don't mean to sound mean, but this is a bit of a sore point for me. Consider the fellow that is 5-8 and 180 lbs/81 k and 12% fat. He's strong as an ox and twice as handsome. BMI will suggest to him that he's overweight. This veritable man of bronze is overweight! No, BMI is not good for anyone anywhere. Do not use.

Comment: Are you thinking of me @MrBoJangles?? :)

Comment: Maybe I am and maybe I am. ☺

Comment: Agree, BMI is trash. I mean honestly it only applies in the extreme cases of being severely overweight or severely underweight.

Comment: @MrBoJangles BMI is a fine metric, yes there are outliers but this occurs in any metric. However, for a given member of the population, if BMI says you are overweight you are probably have too much body fat.

Answer (score 0):

Since i have also started working out in gym since few months and have lost few kgs so here is my opinion. You have not mentioned properly about workout.In order to burn fat you need to have more muscle, the amount of muscle you have is directly proportional to calories you burn. Add weight training to your routine and food which has good amount of lean protein(egg whites, paneer, chicken breast, fish etc) which help in muscle building.

You should always focus on building muscle to loose weight. Have a mix of weight training and cardio.Crunches will help you grow abdominal muscle but will not reduce your belly fat if you have beleived so.You should include more of compound exercises like deadlift,squats etc... to burn more fat.Avoid completely junk food and reduce the sugar intake.You can ask for more questions if you have any particular doubts